# Why is my media query putting elements out of their container?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, css-float, clearfix

Hello Community: I am learning GridSystems right now. I made 2 media queries depending on the screen size: the first one is for 768px the second one is for 480px. but when i adapt the screen size, the elements are coming out of their container. Why? I already have applied the clearfix hack.
I want that the elements dont come out of their container element.(not necessarily .container but every container element.)

```css
html,body{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
}

.container{
  width:95%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  background-color:yellow;
}
.container::after{
  content:"";
  clear:both;
  display:block;
}

.row{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:50px;
  border:5px solid orange;
  width:auto;
}

.col{
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:100%;
  border:5px solid red;
  width:auto;
}
.col-1{width:16.6666%;}
.col-2{width:33.3333%;}
.col-3{width:50%;}
.col-4{width:100%;}

/*Wichtige Viewports
  >1200+px:Desktop
  768px:Tablet Hochformat;
  480px:Handy Querformat
*/

@media(max-width:768px){
  .col-1{width:50%}
  .col-2{width:50%}
}

@media(max-width:480px){
  .col-1{width:100%}
  .col-2{width:100%}
  .col-3{width:100%}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-1"></div>
                <div class="col col-1"></div>
                <div class="col col-1"></div>
                <div class="col col-1"></div>
                <div class="col col-1"></div>
                <div class="col col-1"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-2"></div>
                <div class="col col-2"></div>
                <div class="col col-2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-3"></div>
                <div class="col col-3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col col-4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: you are making your element height:100% so they will logically overflow if you put them in different line --> N * 100% > 1 * 100%

Comment: removing this makes it worse. now it even overflows when viewport is <768px

Comment: you should not remove it, you should rethink your logic .. if you remove it you will make height=0 (and it will be worse ..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

- I'd suggest to not set parent `.row` elements height explicit
- but ruther set it on child elements `.col` - if needed - even better to not have it set but leave natural flow of elements to populate from inside out
- add pseudo clearfix on row class

I've commented this in css block editor this points so see if this clears your doughts

There are frameworks like bootstrap and bunch others that do this auto for you, but it's much better to take low path and learn how things work under the hub - cheers

```css
html,
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.row {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* height: 50px; 
    I'd suggest to not have explicit height set on parent
  */
  border: 5px solid orange;
  width: auto;
}
/* set row's after pseudo to clear floats of child elems - short clearfix */
.row:after{
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.col {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 2em; /* but would suggest to set height of child elements - .col's */
  border: 5px solid red;
  width: auto;
}

.col-1 {
  width: 16.6666%;
}

.col-2 {
  width: 33.3333%;
}

.col-3 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-4 {
  width: 100%;
}


/*Wichtige Viewports
  >1200+px:Desktop
  768px:Tablet Hochformat;
  480px:Handy Querformat
*/

@media(max-width:768px) {
  .col-1 {
    width: 50%
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 50%
  }
}

@media(max-width:480px) {
  .col-1 {
    width: 100%
  }
  .col-2 {
    width: 100%
  }
  .col-3 {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-1"></div>
    <div class="col col-1"></div>
    <div class="col col-1"></div>
    <div class="col col-1"></div>
    <div class="col col-1"></div>
    <div class="col col-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-2"></div>
    <div class="col col-2"></div>
    <div class="col col-2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-3"></div>
    <div class="col col-3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```